# Storing values from TextBox in GridView to DataBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a `GridView` in which i have placed textbox in item template of each column. I want to store the values which I will be entering in the textboxes to the database on button click.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Visible = true;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string UserID = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
        string q="insert into details (name) values('"+UserID+"')";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

the problem is that the textboxes are not even visible when i run the page.

Comment: It wont work this way,search for 'Adding controls dynamically to gridview and retrieve the values'

Comment: Please show your gridview source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get reference of textbox from grid directly.
So first you need to find the textbox from each row of grid.
Code should be like this..

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GridView1.Visible = true;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   ## add below code ##
    TextBox txtUsrId=(TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Your textbox id");
    string UserID = txtUsrId.Text;

    string q="insert into details (name) values('"+UserID+"')";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

}

let me know..

Answer (score 0):

This statement is wrong-

```
 string UserID = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
```

You cannot directly access a subcontrol's value. Do it like this-

```
TextBox tt = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("your text box");
string UserId= tt.Text;
```

And coming to your issue, you should be showing your Gridview source to get help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 TotalRecords = 0;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.\; Integrated Security=SSPI; initial catalog=Testdb;User ID=sa;password=abc123;");            

    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
    {            
        TextBox textBox1 = (TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("textBox1");

        String q = "INSERT INTO details ([name]) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);

        con.Open();
        TotalRecords += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    lblMessage.Text = "Total " + TotalRecords + " inserted successfully.";

}
```

About the textboxes not being displayed on the page, check if the **Visible** property of either GridView, TemplateField or the TextBox it self is not set to **false**. (As you are making the gridview visible in the button click event.)

Also I would not recommend inserting records this way. Rather I would create a strored procedure & pass parameters instead, to avoid [SQL INJECTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection).